# Json (fasterxml) stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, json, spring, data-binding, fasterxml

When trying to serialize a Category I get a stackoverflow.

**Exception**

> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet dispatcher threw exception java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2279)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1501)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:660)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
public class Category implements DataObject, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne @JsonIgnore 
    private Category parent;


@Override
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Category getParent() {
   return null;//return parent;
}

public void setParent(Category parent) {
   // this.parent = parent;
}

public boolean isMainCategory()
{
   return true;// return this.parent == null;
}

/**
 * Returns the chain of parent categories with the main category on index 0
 * @return Chain of categories 
 */
public List<Category> getParentChain()
{

   List<Category> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    Category current = this;
    while(!current.isMainCategory())
    {
        cats.add(current);
        current = current.getParent();
    }
    cats.add(current);
    Collections.reverse(cats);
    return cats;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.title;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if(!(o instanceof Category))return false;
    Category c = (Category)o;

    return c.title.equals(this.title);
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return super.hashCode();
} 
}
```

**Rest Controller function**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Category> get(@PathVariable("id") long categoryId)
{
    Category c  =  service.getCategoryRepository().ReadValue(categoryId);
    if(c == null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(c,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Note**

Even when I replace `return new ResponseEntity<>(c,HttpStatus.OK);` with `return new ResponseEntity<>(new Category(),HttpStatus.OK);` I will get a stackoverflow whilist none of the fields contain a value.

It works fine with my other classes it's only this class that causes a stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Expected ':' instead of 't' error when returning List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848789/spring-expected-instead-of-t-error-when-returning-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably if you comment `private Category parent;` you will not have the StackOverflow. I've got the same problem in a project with circular dependencies.

The best way to solve this problem is to use the id of the parent instead of the Class like:

```
private Long parentId;
```

Edit:

The problem is with `getParentChain()` that is trying to be serialized. By adding @JsonIgnore before the method the problem was resolved.

Comment: I tried, but sadly that doesn't work either. I did a clean build to make sure, but still the same result

Comment: Can you please specify what are the '//and some functions' ?

Comment: What if you comment getParentChain() ?

Comment: Ha, that was the problem. I didn't know you could use @JsonIgnore by a function but apparently you can.

Comment: @JsonIgnore
public Parent getParent() {
  return parent;
 },.......would solve the problem of circular dependency.

Answer (score 14):

Sure thing, `@JsonIgnore` does the job. But what if we need ignored field in our JSON output?

The solution is very simple.

We annotate our 'guilty' field by `@JsonManagedReference` annotation on the one side of our relation (which means our `@ManyToMany` annotation).

And `@JsonBackReference` on the other side of relation (where `@OneToMany` has been placed).

And that's it. No more recursive loops.

Comment: I think that where he sais `@ManyToMany` he should say `@ManyToOne` instead.

Answer (score 7):

One annotation solves your problem.

Add following annotation on class.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
      property = "id")
```

Other way is to annotate on Collections **@JsonManagedReference** for forward direction and **@JsonBackReference.** for backward direction in mapping.

example:

```
public class User{
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<Address> s = new Hashset<>();
}

public class Address{
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    User user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do to avoid this recursive hell.

Add `@JsonIgnore` to every single `@OneToMany(mappedBy="xxxx")` in your JPA Entities

JsonIgnore is from `jackson-annotations`

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

JPA Entity example:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the categoria database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Categoria.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Categoria c")
@XmlRootElement(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="categoria_id")
    private int categoriaId;

    private String descripcion;

    @JsonIgnore
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Establecimiento
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categoria")
    private List<Establecimiento> establecimientos;

    public Categoria() {
    }

    public int getCategoriaId() {
        return this.categoriaId;
    }

    public void setCategoriaId(int categoriaId) {
        this.categoriaId = categoriaId;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public List<Establecimiento> getEstablecimientos() {
        return this.establecimientos;
    }

    public void setEstablecimientos(List<Establecimiento> establecimientos) {
        this.establecimientos = establecimientos;
    }

    public Establecimiento addEstablecimiento(Establecimiento establecimiento) {
        getEstablecimientos().add(establecimiento);
        establecimiento.setCategoria(this);

        return establecimiento;
    }

    public Establecimiento removeEstablecimiento(Establecimiento establecimiento) {
        getEstablecimientos().remove(establecimiento);
        establecimiento.setCategoria(null);

        return establecimiento;
    }

}
```