# Spring Expected ':' instead of 't' error when returning List?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I've got a simple `RequestMapping` method that returns a list of `Users`, the `Users` model has a `ONE TO MANY` relation to `HolidayDates`...I'm just playing around with it, so I've chosen holiday dates as the relation (list of dates they went on a holiday).

So `ONE` user can have `MANY` related `Dates`.

#### User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="about")
    private String about;

    // Maybe change to fetchtype eager
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "holidayDates")
    private Set<HolidayDates> holidayDates;
    public void setHolidayDates(Set<HolidayDates> holidayDates) {
        this.holidayDates = holidayDates;
    }
    public Set<HolidayDates> getHolidayDates() {
        return holidayDates;
    }
    ...Other setters and getters
```

#### HolidayDate model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="holiday_dates")
public class HolidayDates {
//
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="holidayId")
    private int holidayId;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    private String startDate;

    @Column(name="end_date" )
    private String endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
```

When I goto find all Users & their related holiday dates, using the code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> user(@PathVariable String name) {
    List<User> user = userService.findAll();
    // Simply implementing List<User> findAll(); from userService auto wired field

    return user;
}
```

The userService has an `@autowired` field to `userDao`, which simply extends JPA repository:

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository <User, Integer> {
```

Now when I run a `GET` request on the controller, it returns the following response:

```
Expected ':' instead of 't'
```

As well as a big long stack trace of fasterxml.jackson errors:

```
[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
```

Doesn't spring handle all this `jpa/model` to `json` conversion?

Comment: There appears to be a typo in `User` at `@Column(name="userId\`")` (note the \` after `userId`).

Comment: I fixed that, that isn't actually in my code! Not sure what happened when copy and pasting into SO. I've fixed the question @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Should `@Table(name="holiday_daes")` be `@Table(name="holiday_dates")`?

Comment: Another typo, fixed. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: is there stackoverflow error in your server error log?

Comment: Since you are using Dates as String I bet that there are something wrong on your data that it is not properly binded to a json object.

Comment: Shouldn't spring handle turning the models into json? @JorgeCampos

Comment: or is there error of org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Comment: Nah, there isn't @andy

Comment: Looks like there is an infinite recursion going on... you might want to add `@JsonIgnore` to `getUser` in `HolidayDates`... or remove `user` all together from `HolidayDates`, unless you need it to be there...

Comment: @jny - That fixed it, wanna pop it in an answer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion going on during serialization since `User` refers to `HolidayDates` and `HolidayDates` refer to `User`.  You can stop it by adding `@JsonIgnore` to `getUser` in `HolidayDates`.

Comment: Odd that it didn't show this in the stack trace...But I have a feeling the stack trace was too long to fit in my terminal window, and thus why it wasn't shown.

Comment: But when you do that the json doesn't include the data?

Comment: @jny `@JsonIgnore` annotation simply ignores one of the sides of the relationship, thus breaking the chain. This marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality. That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter" or "creator". So result will be incomplete means only parent class properties will be fetched and not related child class properties. To overcome this use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`

Answer (score 2):

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<HolidayDates> holidayDates;
```

and

```
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is because of infinite recursion between entity classes use @JsonIgnore for older versions and this code for newer versions.

```
 @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "queue_group",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Queue> queues;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "qid")
       // @JsonIgnore
        @JsonBackReference
        private Queue_group queue_group;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same your error, but in my case cause I'm missing implement default constructor.

```
public User() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree the correct answer to the question is the accepted answer by jny, I got exactly the same problem by having a bad Jackson objectMapper config installed in Spring Boot which for some reason, instead of fixing date serialization, messed up the serialization of an entirely different class. I removed the following code and things started working again. Just puting this here in case someone has the same problem

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
//  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add **@JsonManagedReference**  in your User model and **@JsonBackReference** for HolidayDates model

User model:

```
@OneToMany
 @JsonManagedReference
 private Set<HolidayDates> holidayDates;
```

HolidayDate model:

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old post but I faced similar issue where back reference application was going in loop and I was getting similar kind of error. I wanted dependent object to be included in to be retained on either side of the entity. `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonIdentityInfo` were not helping. You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` instead.

In class `User`

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"user"})
private Set<HolidayDates> holidayDates;
```

and in `HolidayDates`

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"holidayDates"})
private User user;
```

This way worked for me very well. This post http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html?m=1 explains pros and cons of each of the above annotations.